# Why does a4paper add a skip between the figure caption and the following text?

Tags: captions, vertical-spacing

I am still in the process to vertically adjust the image and the following caption. Through this question a new question arose. What is the skip between a caption and the following text? And where is the `figure` environment defined in the LaTeX kernel (which file), so that I can investigate something like this myself?

As you can see in my example, the skip is more than the baselineskip and I want to set it up myself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0mm,right=40mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}

\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0bp}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0bp}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate(upper) at ($(current page.north east) - (2.5,0)$);
\coordinate(lower) at ($(current page.south east) - (2.5,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

This is a
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x.base)]
\node(x){Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=170mm,height=63.99mm]{example-image-a}%
    \caption[]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base),remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt](x){Just};} a test}%
\end{figure}

\tikz[baseline=(y.base),remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt](y){This};} is a line of text to show what happens below the figure.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,draw=red]%
\coordinate(x1) at (x.base west);
\coordinate(x2) at (x.base east);
\coordinate(x3) at (intersection of upper--lower and x1--x2);
\draw (x.base west) -- (x3);
\coordinate(y1) at (y.base west);
\coordinate(y2) at (y.base east);
\coordinate(y3) at (intersection of upper--lower and y1--y2);
\draw (y.base west) -- (y3);
\coordinate(nextbaseline1) at ($(y.base west) - (0,12bp)$);
\coordinate(nextbaseline2) at ($(nextbaseline1) + (1,0)$);
\coordinate(nextbaseline3) at (intersection of upper--lower and nextbaseline1--nextbaseline2);
\draw (nextbaseline1) -- (nextbaseline3);
\draw[->] ($(x3) - (0.5cm,0)$) -- ++(0,-12bp)node[midway,right]{more than 12bp};
\draw[->] ($(y3) - (0.5cm,0)$) -- ++(0,-12bp)node[midway,right]{baselineskip=12bp};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

The problem seems to be the `a4paper` option of geometry. What the hack does change with `a4paper` that makes a skip from the caption to the following text? Using `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` has the same problem, by the way.

Comment: `\textfloatsep`

Comment: @MadyYuvi But I set textfloatsep to 0bp in my example, how can this be extra space?

Comment: If you remove the `\tikz[baseline=(x.base),remember picture]{\node(x){Just};}` and write only `Just` then there is no space gap between lines. And do the same with `This`.

Comment: @MadyYuvi not for h floats, h floats have `\intextsep` before and after

Comment: if you want to measure/control the space from the image to the following text it would be more consistent not to mark it as a `figure` as that takes the content out of the text flow and allows it to be re-inserted at a different point, so the text that happens to be after it here isn't really "following" the figure.

Comment: unrelated but `\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}` means that you have no math sizes set so in a real document you would probably want to re-configure the math settings after such a redefinition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle of course, I am abusing `\normalsize` here, but I wanted to avoid any possibility of glue beeing inserted where I don't know. And the `[h]` is just for illustration to have text before and after the figure. Hence yes this MWE probably doesn't make sense it is just convenient to show the inserted extra space that I am looking for.

Comment: some of it is added by the tikz I think , add inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt on both

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for that hint, I was a bit blind in my MWE. I was first investigating with `scrartcl` and then with `article`. In `scrartcl` the problem was there all the time, so I added the `TikZ` to visualize and then replaced `scrartcl` with `article` for the MWE. However I found the critical detail is the page size. Check my new MWE with and without the `a4paper` option and see for yourself, that this adds additional white space!

Comment: Actually, it comes from somewhere else, try adding a blank line above `\begin{figure}[h]`, then it does not matter if `a4paper` is there or not

Comment: More fun. Don't add a blank line, use this lipsum: `\lipsum[1-2]\strut` now the distance is too short. Thus there is a reason why I always add floats as paragraphs of their own.

Comment: @daleif this is really strange to me, but probably makes a lot of sense if you know the background. I have no issue with having the figure in it's own paragraph, but then try it with `\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=40mm]{geometry}` and you will have too much whitespace again.

Comment: The position of the figure in the surrounding text depend on the depth of the last line before the figure. If this lat line does not include g, y etc. then the position of the figure differs.

Comment: @wipet that cannot be the reason alone, because if you change from `article` to `scrartcl` and keep `geometry` options consistent, the line has the same content.

Comment: No. Try to put a single word without the depth to the last line. Then add g. Watch the difference.

Comment: Or add a strut at the end of the `\lipsum`

Comment: If there is no `\par` before the figure then the figure is created inside `\vadjust` and the horizontal mode follows after figure. This is one of obscure behaviour of LaTeX :).

Comment: @wipet see my example below, I have paragraphs between and there is a `q` on the line before the image. But still there is a gap untill I add the `\strut`

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Here is a simpler MWE with less tikz code
Note the difference when you remove the `%` before the `\strut`

```
%\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

% placed here if some package or class decides on doing at begin
% document stuff
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0bp}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0bp}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0bp}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont}

\normalsize


This is a \lipsum[1]%\strut

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=170mm,height=63.99mm]{example-image-a}%
    \caption[]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base),remember picture]{\node[inner
        sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt](x){Just};} a test g}%
\end{figure}

\noindent
\tikz[baseline=(y.base),remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer
  sep=0pt](y){This};} is a line of text to show what happens below the
figure is a line of text to show what happens below the figure is a
line of text to show what happens below the figure
\tikz[baseline=(z.base),remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt,outer
  sep=0pt](z){This};}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,draw=red]%

  \draw (x.base west -| current page.west) -- (x.base west -| current page.east) coordinate (a);
  \draw (y.base west -| current page.west) -- (y.base west -| current page.east) coordinate (b);
  \draw (z.base west -| current page.west) -- (z.base west -| current page.east);

  \draw[->] ($(a)+(-3,0)$) -- ++(0,-12bp) node[midway,right] {\tiny 12bp arrow};
  \draw[->] ($(b)+(-3,0)$) -- ++(0,-12bp) node[midway,right] {\tiny 12bp arrow};

  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```